# Execute a linux command to copy pdf files in a text file to a directory

Tags: linux, shell, cp

I have a list of pdf files in my text file called "pdf.txt".How to copy this to a directory /home/temporary using linux command.

```
#!/bin/bash
pdf=cat pdf.txt
cp -R $pdf /home/temporary/b
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one file per line, this should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' # split on newlines, not whitespace in case filenames have spaces
for line in $(cat pdf.txt); do
    cp "${line}" /home/temporary/b
done
```